# google map not working in my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one application for showing the map but it is not working does not show the map.
I created the application with target name Google Apps platform is 2.3 and my emulator is Google apps(API level 9)

this is my android manifest.xml

I get the following error in the logcat file

```
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps-1.apk]
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps-1.apk]
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
04-06 12:32:27.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(476):     ... 11 more
```

please tell me how to correct my problem

Comment: make sure, it would be Google API, not Google Apps

Comment: How can we understand your logcat error, its not correct way to represent your questions. try to use code sample to display.

Comment: is it needed to add any external jar file....

Comment: i have given <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in the manifest also and given internet permission

Comment: @murali_ma: Can you please provide your manifest file code. I think there is some error......Provide manifest file code so that error coulde be checked

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ..>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">                  
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />           
            <intent-filter>
               ...
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

Comment: @murali_ma: why are you using <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> this inside the activity.... I have answered your question what it must be like...try using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure in ur manifest as u added the google map library within the application tag instead of giving it outside.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".GoogleMapView"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you created the api key? and keep in mind that you need one key for debug certificate and a second key for the release
android:apiKey="xxx"
[generate api key](http://code.google.com/intl/de/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)

Comment: i found the MD5 finger print key and received the api key,

Comment: it shows the error to be as ClassNotFoundException...i have given permissions in the manifest file...what it means

Comment: maybe a missing <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in the manifest? you have to add the uses statement between the application tags

Comment: please post your Manifest File and the xml of the MapView

Comment: this is my main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="0VwTqHDTTNQOdV9uedg-srDDhQbOnIihpl23zIA"
        />
 
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: this is my android manifest.xml

<manifest ....>
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">                  
       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />           
            <intent-filter>
               .....
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

Answer (score 1):

permission should exist in following way:

This link may also help you http://www.androidpeople.com/android-google-map-application-example

Comment: <?xml version="1.0? encoding="utf-8??>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
......>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<activity android:name=".SampleMapApplication"
android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>

Comment: It must be something like this...... Try this .......as changing the position of user permission as shown in above comment

Comment: @murali_ma: I don't know my code was not showing in answer that's why I wrote it in comment

Comment: @murali_ma: You have two duplicate questions .......either delete this question or accept the right one. As this is not the right way! You must do anyone thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have obtained a maps key from Google by generating a MD5 hash of your debug/release keys?

What's the output that you see , if you see any ?

Have you given `InternetPermission` to your app?

Answer (score 0):

check if you have used the use-library for google map and  permission for Internet in your manifest file and also have you used the debug key in xml .

Comment: And what about the debug key......have you used the correct debug key for your app...?

Comment: yes i use   keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\IXM_F1_B8\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android-keypass androidandroiddebugkey, Jul 24, 2010, PrivateKeyEntry,Certificate fingerprint (MD5):BF:88:06:A3:15:76:B2:83:81:E0:71:C9:43:1A:52:68  and i got key from google .